# Simulating mixer phase detector in ADS using harmonic balance problem

Tags: phase, mixer

There is a basic property of a mixer in which it could used as a phase detector as shown in the theory below.

A circuit was built where there two sources with same frequency but difference phase as shown bellow but HB simulation doesn't show DC values.

How can I simulate my phase detector in ADS?

Is HB the right tool? Is there some better alternatives in ADS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You always write 'bellow' when you mean 'below' (the first is a type of howl or scream, the second means down or beneath).